# Why they show 1 times for the answer but already create 2 threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I want the threads to show odd and even number and I've already created 2 threads but when I run it, it shows only 1 thread.

My question is how I can call the even and odd number using threads?

This is a sample output when I'm running my code. I need the number odd and even between 0 and 9.

```
Please input x:
0
Please input y:
9
Even 0

this is my code for calling threads

public class MyRunnable {

       public static void main(String[] args) {

           Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
           System.out.println("Please input x:");
           int x= in.nextInt();
           System.out.println("Please input y:");
           int y=in.nextInt();

           TaskEvenOdd  oddRunnable=new TaskEvenOdd (1,x,y);
           TaskEvenOdd  evenRunnable=new TaskEvenOdd (0,x,y);

           Thread t1=new Thread(oddRunnable,"Odd");
           Thread t2=new Thread(evenRunnable,"Even");

           t1.start();
           t2.start();

       }
   }


package com.company;
//import java.util.Scanner;

public class TaskEvenOdd implements Runnable {
   private final int remainder;
   private int x;
   private final int y;
   static final Object lock=new Object();


   // standard constructors
  public TaskEvenOdd (int remainder,int x, int y){
       this.remainder = remainder;
       this.x = x;
       this.y = y;
   }


   @Override
   public void run() {
       while (x< y) {
           synchronized (lock) {
               while (x % 2 != remainder) { // wait for numbers other than remainder
                   try {
                       lock.wait();
                   } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                   }
               }
               System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " " + x);
              x++;
               lock.notifyAll();
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: can you add `Thread.sleep(2000)` at end of the main method

Comment: There is a discrepancy in the code you posted. Class `TaskEvenOdd` has a single constructor that takes exactly one parameter yet in class `MyRunnable` you call a constructor with three parameters. Please [edit] you question so as to make your code a valid [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is in TaskEvenOdd. Share code for the class in your question.

For reference here is my implementation:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please input x:");
        int x= in.nextInt();    
        System.out.println("Please input y:");
        int y=in.nextInt();

        TaskEvenOdd  oddRunnable=new TaskEvenOdd (1,x,y);
        TaskEvenOdd  evenRunnable=new TaskEvenOdd (0,x,y);

        Thread t1=new Thread(oddRunnable,"Odd");
        Thread t2=new Thread(evenRunnable,"Even");

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }

}

class TaskEvenOdd implements Runnable {
    private int odd;
    private int start;
    private int end;
    
    public TaskEvenOdd(int oddEven, int start, int end) {
        this.odd = oddEven;
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        String name = Thread.currentThread().getName();
        for (int i = start; i <= end; i++) {
            if(i%2==odd) {
                System.out.println(name + " " + i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Please input x:
0
Please input y:
9
Even 0
Even 2
Even 4
Even 6
Even 8
Odd 1
Odd 3
Odd 5
Odd 7
Odd 9
```

Comment: may i know how the code to passing the data? like it using different odd,even ,start .how it detect the user'input?

Comment: i just confuse and not understanding ,can you expalain it?

Comment: When you executed `new TaskEvenOdd (1,x,y);` you passed the data to the object via constructor `public TaskEvenOdd(int oddEven, int start, int end)`. The constructor stores the data in fields `odd,start,end`. The class fields are accessible in class methods. So these fields are visible in method `run()`. For more information refer [this article](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/class.html)

Comment: ok now i understand ,very thank you !!!

Comment: why using this "throws IOException"??

Comment: :P this is a test class. I try code here. Ignore the throws clause. I've updated the answer.

Comment: okay i just wonder why. Haha thanks for explanations

Answer (score 2):

You can do so by synchronising a method that prints odd and even alternatively e.g.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class TaskEvenOdd {
    synchronized void printEvenOdd(int x, int y) throws InterruptedException {
        for (int i = x; i < y; i++) {
            String currentThreadName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
            if (currentThreadName.equals("Even")) {
                if (i % 2 == 0) {
                    System.out.println("Thread " + currentThreadName + " " + i);
                    notify();
                } else {
                    wait();
                }
            } else if (currentThreadName.equals("Odd")) {
                if (i % 2 == 1) {
                    System.out.println("Thread " + currentThreadName + " " + i);
                    notify();
                } else {
                    wait();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please input x: ");
        int x= in.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Please input y: ");
        int y=in.nextInt();

        TaskEvenOdd eo = new TaskEvenOdd();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                eo.printEvenOdd(x, y);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        Thread t2 = new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                eo.printEvenOdd(x, y);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        t1.setName("Odd");
        t2.setName("Even");
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Please input x: 0
Please input y: 10
Thread Even 0
Thread Odd 1
Thread Even 2
Thread Odd 3
Thread Even 4
Thread Odd 5
Thread Even 6
Thread Odd 7
Thread Even 8
Thread Odd 9
```